# Comparing two dates i javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker, date-comparison

I want to compare the picked date with the current date. But the if always falls thru to else. I read a couple of posts that the if will always return false because the two dates are two diffretnt object but contains the same time.
I tried `getTime()` but didnt get it to work either. What i want to achive in the end with this comparison is I want to restrict date input after 09:30 in the morning (24h) if the picked date is today. Is this the right way to go? To filter out the date first and then the time of day? Appriciate all the help I can get! I couldnt get the JSFiddle to work. wanted to give a live sample.

```
  $('#startDatePicker').datepicker({

  var fromDate = $('#startDatePicker').datepicker('getDate');
  var today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0).getTime();
  selectedDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0).getTime();

  if (today === fromDate ) {
    alert("Today")

  } else {


  };
});
```

Comment: `selectedDate` comes from nothing ..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: Sorry.@Teemu. Fixed it.

Comment: Thanks!! @jajasuperman. Apperantly i didnt search hard enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that [`jQuery UI's datepicker`](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)? If yes, then you need to add `onSelect` as a property to your datepicker parameter.

```
$('#startDatePicker').datepicker({
  onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
    var today = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    var selected = new Date(selectedDate).getTime();

    if (today === selected) {
      alert('Today');
    } else {
      // Do something.
      console.log(selected);
    }
  }
});
```

```js
$(function () {
  $('#startDatePicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
      var today = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
      var selected = new Date(selectedDate).getTime();
      
      if (today === selected) {
        alert('Today');
      } else {
        // Do something.
        console.log(selected);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="startDatePicker" />
```